# How to "flip" and change the sign of one particular row of this matrix?

Tags: matrices, transformation, block-matrices

I would like to transform the following matrix : 
$\mathbf A$ =$\ \begin{bmatrix}
a&b\\
c&d\\
e&f\\
g&h
\end{bmatrix}\ $ into this one : $\mathbf B$ = $\ \begin{bmatrix}
g&-h\\
e&-f\\
c&-d\\
a&-b
\end{bmatrix}\ $.

I can easily transform each column separately by doing these operations :

$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&0&1\\
0&0&1&0\\
0&1&0&0\\
1&0&0&0
\end{bmatrix} \ \begin{bmatrix}
a\\
c\\
e\\
g
\end{bmatrix}  = \begin{bmatrix}
g\\
e\\
c\\
a
\end{bmatrix}\\
\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&0&-1\\
0&0&-1&0\\
0&-1&0&0\\
-1&0&0&0
\end{bmatrix} \ \begin{bmatrix}
b\\
d\\
f\\
h
\end{bmatrix}  = \begin{bmatrix}
-h\\
-f\\
-d\\
-b
\end{bmatrix}
\end{array}
\right.
$

But doing this wont provide with the matrix $\mathbf B$. Sure I can concatenate the two matrices after doing two separate operations. But I would like to do this in only one operation...

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is finding matrices $X,Y$ such that $XAY=B$ good enough for you?

Comment: Well, in fact it would be good enough... I just did not think about that... Anyways, I tried the answer proposed by Jonathan, but it wasn't enough... any clues?

Comment: Jonathan updated his answer. It works as it is now.

Comment: You're right, I didn't see it in time...

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer if you feel like it's good enough for you and you don't want any other answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Multiply on the right by
$$\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}$$
and on the left by
$$\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0&1\\0&0&1&0\\0&1&0&0\\1&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: Well, that was fast! Thank you very much... I was stuck with this for like an hour...

Comment: Glad to help. These are so-called elementary matrices, and they do predictable things to columns (when you multiply on one side) or to rows (when you multiply on the other side).

Comment: I didn't know about them... Thanks for the information! I'm looking for them all right now in my books!